# React/Redux - New props - componentDidUpdate not called

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on a new React/Redux code base. I have a component connected to Redux through a container component. Basically, there is a piece of data within the store that has an id. That id corresponds to a conversation that needs to be loaded. When that number changes, we have a new prop. The component re-renders. And the componentDidUpdate method SHOULD be called... except it is not.

Again:

New data comes in (I have confirmed this with a console.log)
Component re-renders (I have confirmed this with a console.log)

...but componentDidUpdate is not called. I need it to be called.

I looked in Redux state, and the state changes. But there is no difference in Redux tools. I can visually see the data changing in state, but redux tools detects no "difference." AKA, even though the raw data is changing, the system does not detect it.

Could this happen if a reducer returns a mutated, original copy of state rather than a new copy?

Comment: First of all you really need to add some relevant code. Second, there is **no way** `componentDidUpdate()` didn't fire at all after a `render()` (except the initial call). You are missing something but without your code it is hard to tell what exactly.

Comment: Can't. Not able to share. Code is the company's. It is. I can tell you, it re-renders. I have a console log inside render. It re-renders.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I've got my hands tied with sharing.

Comment: Understood. Can you post some mockup based off the original code that doesn't reveal any company algorithms?

Comment: To answer your question: yes, a mutating reducer could prevent components from updating, even if the new data is visible when the store is logged to the console. You could try passing `{pure: false}` as the options object to `connect` to see if this is the case.